# Subsetting a dataframe in R based on the elements in the columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe [df](/questions/tagged/df) which has 5 rows and 6 columns.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Hits = c("Hit1", "Hit2", "Hit3", "Hit4", "Hit5"),
  category1 = c("a1", "", "b1", "a1", "c1"),
  category2 = c("", "", "", "", "a2"),
  category3 = c("a3", "", "b3", "", "a3"),
  category4 = c("", "", "", "", ""),
  category5 = c("", "", "a5", "b5", ""),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

[image]

From each of the columns [category1](/questions/tagged/category1) to [category5](/questions/tagged/category5), I need to retain only the elements which appear at the topmost position i.e.

[image]

and finally, drop the rows having no elements in these five columns, i.e.

[image]

How do I achieve this in the simplest possible way in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  #Retain only the values that appear in topmost position
  mutate(across(starts_with('category'), ~replace(., -match(TRUE, . != ''), ''))) %>%
  #Drop the rows that have no element
  filter(if_any(starts_with('category'), ~. != ''))

#  Hits category1 category2 category3 category4 category5
#1 Hit1        a1                  a3                    
#2 Hit3                                                a5
#3 Hit5                  a2
```

---

If you want to do this via position you can do -

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(2:6, ~replace(., -match(TRUE, . != ''), ''))) %>%
  filter(if_any(2:6, ~. != ''))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. I'm wondering if there is a way to tweak your method for cases where the column names could vary.

Comment: What would be the column names? There are lot of functions in `dplyr` that you can use to select columns. `starts_with`, `ends_with`, `matches`, `contains` etc. Also you can select columns also by position `2:5`.

Comment: Okay. I guess selecting the columns based on positions will solve the issue of varying column names. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Could you please show how to select columns based on their positions? I'm not aware of the syntax

Comment: What are the position of the columns that you want to select?

Comment: You can take the example that I mentioned in the question (i.e. column positions 2-6)

Comment: I have added an additional part to my question. Do you have a solution to it?

Comment: @AbhishekChowdhury Can you ask that as a new question? 1. Every question should be focussed on only one specific question. This confuses future readers. 2. It is not a good practice to change your question after you have received an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = -Hits, .fns = ~ifelse(row_number() == first(which(.!="")) | all(. == ""), ., ""))) %>% 
  filter(if_any(-Hits, ~.!=""))

  Hits category1 category2 category3 category4 category5
1 Hit1        a1                  a3                    
2 Hit3                                                a5
3 Hit5                  a2
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This works but I want empty spaces instead of <NA>. Could you edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: There's still <NA> under category4.

Comment: @AbhishekChowdhury Solved!